No connection between the steering wheel and the AgOpen controller with CAN
I'm developing the AgOpen navigation system for a tractor and I'm having trouble connecting the controller to the Keya steering wheel via CAN bus.  Everything was working fine at home on the desk, but when I installed the navigation in the tractor, I must have damaged something because now the steering wheel doesn't turn. When I connect via RS232 using the manufacturer's software, the steering wheel works, so the motor is definitely functional.
On the left is the controller, and on the right is the steering wheel. I measured the resistance just to make sure the connections are good.

this is the CAN diagram in the controller

I don't have an oscilloscope, but I connected an Arduino to the CAN bus to measure the signals. The scale on the left is in mV
This is signal from controller between CANL and GND. it's between ~0.5V-2.5V

This is signal from controller between CANH and GND. it's between ~2.5V-4.5V

This is signal from steering wheel between CANL and GND.

This is signal from steering wheel between CANH and GND.

I connected the controller to the steering wheel and this is what the signal looks like:
This is signal between CANL and GND.

This is signal between CANH and GND.

Is the CAN signal supposed to look like this?. CAN in the controller looks good, but is it probably damaged in the steering wheel? Should I replace the SN65HVD1050 module?

Assuming it is a point to point link, do you have termination on both sides?

Yes, 120 ohm in wheel, and 33.6K in controller

no, the controller has 120 ohm resistor, but between CANL CANH is 33.6K, I added a diagram to the question.

The scope prints are gibberish, to the point where I'd suspect a measurement error. Check probe ground etc.

It's not clear what resistance you got after those comments... do you measure 60 ohm between CANH and CANL when the boards aren't powered? If not, the hardware is bad. On the left pic it looks like you can select the 120R through some solder strap but I might be wrong.

I sent the equipment to a friend from the AgOpen group; he will check it on his controller and steering wheel. I will be sure if the controller or the steering wheel is damaged.
